# Trouble running a PHP script with CRON

Tags: php, cron

I created a php file I want to run all the time. I then created a basic wrapper I want CRON to run to insure the script is still running - and restart it if needed.

My `crontab -e` entry is like this:

```
20 * * * * /var/www/bot/cron.php
```

The contents of cron.php look like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
@exec ('ps aux | grep loop', $output, $ret_var);

$running = false;
foreach ($output as $line)
{
    if (strpos($line, 'bot.php') !== false)
    {
        $running = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (! $running)
{
    @exec('/usr/bin/nohup php ' . __DIR__ . '/bot.php >/var/log/bot_out 2>&1 &');
}

die();
```

However, I'm having trouble getting this working. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm not getting anything on any error log, and `/var/log/bot_out` does show some runtime errors so I know PHP must be called.

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'suhosin' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: This really seems like it should be something that's handled in a bash script, not a PHP script.  Have it check if `ps aux | grep -i loop | grep -i bot.php` is a zero length string.  If it is, launch the bot script, otherwise do nothing.  Secondly, I think that cron line should read: `20 * * * * php /var/www/bot/cron.php`.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?  How do those permissions match up with those you are executing cron as?  Is /usr/bin/php the correct path to your PHP CLI executable?

Comment: @GigaWatt, my bash scripting is weak in this area, do you have an example script?

Comment: Give something like this a shot:
`if [ -z $(ps aux | grep -i loop | grep -i bot.php) ]; then php /some/dir/bot.php; fi`

Comment: @Gigawatt It doesn't need `php` in the cron command as he is using a shebang to identify the path to the PHP executable.

Comment: @MikeBrant - Whoops, didn't see that in there.  I saw the <?php and had a mental blackout.

Comment: If you want to start a program *and keep it running*, then Systemd or Upstart may be easier to work with than Cron.

Comment: you can use `php -q file.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
20 * * * * /var/www/bot/cron.sh
```

then contents of cron.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
KP=$(pgrep -P 1 -f bot.php)
if [ "X$KP" = "X" ]
  then
    /usr/bin/nohup php PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT/bot.php 
fi
```

Comment: Works, but `/usr/bin/nohup: ignoring input and appending output to '/home/user/nohup.out'` Any way to log (or ignore) output?

Comment: Append a `2>/dev/null` after the command.  It'll dump STDERR into the abyss.